# Java problem when adding an element to a Object list

Tags: java, arrays, list, arraylist

The result I want is [Object-oriented, "design":, with, UML's, diagrams]
but the result is [diagrams, diagrams, diagrams, diagrams, diagrams]
When an element is added, the list changes all of its elements to the added elements like this:
[Object-oriented] ["design":, "design":] [with, with, with] [UML's, UML's, UML's, UML's] [diagrams, diagrams, diagrams, diagrams, diagrams]
Why is the list duplicated when I add an element and how to fix it ?

```
public class Doc {
    private String content;
    private String title, body;
    public Doc(String content) {
        this.content = content;
        title= content.substring(0,content.indexOf('\n'));
        body= content.substring(content.indexOf('\n'),content.length());
    }
    public List<Word> getTitle(){
         String[] l1=title.split("\\s");
         List<Word> list= new ArrayList<>();
         for(String word: l1){
            Word element =Word.createWord(word); // createWord is a method initialize a new Word with a parameter is string
            list.add(element);
         }        
         return list;
     }
    public List<Word> getBody(){
        String[] l1=body.split("\\s");
        List<Word> list= new ArrayList<>();
        for(String word: l1){
            list.add(Word.createWord(word));
        }
        return list;
    }
    public boolean equals(Object o){
        return true;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Doc d = new Doc("Object-oriented \"design\": with UML's diagrams\n" +
                         "Definition: An object-oriented system's context made up of (interacting) objects.");
                 System.out.println(d.getTitle());        
        }
```

Comment: that equals method that just returns true, make it right.

Comment: I will fix it later, now I want to handle the getTitle method first

Comment: The bug is in Word.java which you did not supply. This question cannot be answered; there is not enough information available to do so.

Comment: Including all source code that is executed, not just a comment asserting that a function does what you believe it does is much more helpful for determining where you may have gone wrong.

Comment: There are two possible causes: either `Word` contains only a static field for the string or `Word.createWord()` always returns the same `Word` instance and just overwrite the string field of that instance. The linked question explains more details.